# Since looping is bad, how should I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, split

I have a table with records each having a unique Identifier, a start date, and two semi-colon delimited strings which I need to break out into a value for each date with the first date being the start date value for each record.

Currently, I am doing all sorts of bad things, in that I am using a While loop to go through each record in the table (16K records+) and I am using a split function that uses a While loop. The split function is based on Oskar Austegard's `dbo.fnSplit` function.

I've been reading about how using a loop to split is bad for performance, but these delimited strings have at most 100 Items. I am beginning to try to learn about `CROSS APPLY` and I have been using CTEs for several SPs I've created, but I am not sure if using a CTE here would work or how it would work. I especially am not sure on CROSS APPLY or any other APPLY.

I will gladly post my query and the adulterated split function if someone is willing to assist.

Comment: Can you share some sample data in particular, as well as your current code?

Comment: Also a little more detail on how you use the date values split out of the semi-colon delimited strings, explained with that sample data.

Comment: Check out this article. It requires a pretty good understanding of SQL, but perhaps you can modify it to your purposes. Also, showing your code always helps! http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: What version of SQL Server? SQL Server SP1 has `STRING_SPLIT` funciton

Answer (score 1):

Below is the same answer to [this question on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a5bee9d-0194-4a9d-907c-197d63108573/i-know-this-looping-is-bad-so-how-should-i-accomplish-what-i-am-trying-to-do?forum=transactsql).

You were forced into doing bad things because you violated first normal form in your data model(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). A column should not contain a delimited list because the data isn't atomic. Also repeating data should typically be stored as separate rows (probably in a different table with a one-to-many relationship) instead of as columns of the same row.

If you fix your model to more closely adhere to normalization principals, your queries will become much prettier and perform much better too.

Answer (score 0):

> Looping is bad.

.

> I have a table with records each having ... two semi-colon delimited strings... [T]hese delimited strings have at most 100 Items.

You know what's just about as bad as looping, maybe worse? Storing delimited data in single columns. **DON'T DO THAT!**

Instead, add a new table to your database. This table will use the primary key from the original table and space for one single item from the delimited column. So if one row in the original table had 100 items in the delimited column, now you have one hundred rows in the new table that each have the primary key from the original table and just one of the elements from the other column.

Now you can you use queries with a simple `JOIN` to identify each item.